# How to use a environment variable to specify StarTeam Hostname in jenkins?

Tags: properties, jenkins, environment-variables, starteam

We moved from Hudson to Jenkins and are using StarTeam for version control.

Now according to this site (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=47480884) there are no global settings to setup StarTeam config.

So we have to specify the StarTeam configuration manually per project (Jenkins Home/[myProject]/configure 'Source Code Management Section')

Certain properties will always be the same like the HostName and the Port #. Now if we were ever to change the StarTeam server we will have to go to every single project and update it again.

Is there a way that we can specify this in a variable and use it in every project?

We tried to create a global environment var (Jenkins Home/Manage Jenkins/Configure System in the 'Global Properties' section).

[image: Global Properties]

And then under the project I am trying to configure I have

[image: Source Code Management]

But when it is building it has difficulty connection to server ${STARTEAM_SERVER}. Have anyone used this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, the Starteam Jenkins plugin doesn’t understand parameterized values. You have to enter the IP or machine name instead.

Raise issue in Jenkins if you want but I don't think anyone is maintaining the Starteam plugin now.

Comment: Thanks ABose. I have read on some other sites as well and the comment seems to be the same. Though this is not an answer I have marked it as what is currently present as the best answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it works, but you can try a properties.file.

Content of the file which constains the script:

```
echo "STARTTEAM_SERVER=`MyServerNameGoesHere`"> env.properties
```

Path of the properties file:

```
env.properties
```

Source code Management (StartTeam)

```
echo"$STARTTEAM_SERVER"
```

Something like this works for the build, maybe here works too.

Comment: We tried the property file but we were unable to read the values in the Jenkins Editor. Only passing the values to the actual build.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from ABose was correct at the time, but might be worth another look.  As of June 24, Borland closed a vote on their User Voice site. I believe they have finally taken an active role in contributing to the Jenkins plugin.  Not sure if it is the same base or if they have written their own plugin.  I was in conversation with them on this back in 2012, and it seems they may have gotten this going again.  Here's a link: http://borland.uservoice.com/forums/143611-starteam-feature-requests/suggestions/2466059-expanded-build-tool-integrations.

You might try contacting Borland Support to find out more, and bring this feature suggestion to their attention.

Comment: We are in the process of moving to git